# Cannot pick the object with Eyedropper Data-Block in Curve Modifier

Tags: curve-modifier

In Blender 3.4.1 (Mac M1) Eyedropper Data-Block cannot picks ANY object as a Curve Object in Curve Modifier. Neither in Object Mode or Edit Mode.

[image]

Tried different objects (not only circle) - nothing helps.

Comment: Hello, kind of hard to have a definitive answer, please verify that you're actually targetting a curve object, and it looks like you're in edit mode, try in object mode (TAB shortcut)

Comment: That’s an object data block field with an eye dropper, not an eye dropper data block.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried in in both modes - and nothing. I took the eyedropper of Curve modifier and tried to put it on Circle - to make a mesh above (active object) something like tire. But eyedropper has no reaction for the circle (or Empty, or Cube, or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is go to your rounded shape that you want to use. Then you right click, and convert to curve.

Then you can use it with the eye dropper.